# packrat: remove older package versions from src directory

Tags: r, dependency-management, packrat

My `packrat.src` directory contains multiple *.tar.gz files for various libraries.

So for example, the subfolder for `broom` looks like this:

```
broom
├── broom_0.4.1.tar.gz
└── broom_0.4.4.tar.gz
```

What is the correct way to remove, say the older package version, once I checked that that everything is running fine with the newest version?

I checked `packrat:clean()`, but this seems to have a different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all sources within the `src` folder and re-run `packrat::snapshot()`, which should provide a clean `src` directory without old, unused source files.